# DB structure - form with dynamic number of options

Tags: mysql

I've been reading similar questions, but I think my case is a bit more complicated.

I have a form that register items. These items may have options with sub-options (checkboxes and radio buttons):

- The number of checkboxes and radio buttons may decrease/increase but the real pain to design a good structure is for the checkboxes, as these must have (at least I think so) a fixed name column for each one.
- The case for radio buttons is easier as I just assign an id to each one (and save the names in a different table).

My current DB structure is simple (between parenthesis is the table/column name):

- The items table (item) have columns of type integer (to save the id of the radio buttons).
- Another table for the checkboxes (item_option), with columns of type integer (1 if checked, 0 if unchecked). And 1 PK column (item_id) that points to the PK column (id) of the items table.
- And tables (again item_option) for the names of the radio buttons with a PK column (id) that points to the option column (is this understandable? Sorry for my bad english).

I think a different table containing the sub-options is better than put all the columns in the main table, right?

So, the radio buttons are stored in the main table (1 column per option) and the checkboxes in a separeted table (1 table per option):

Items table:

```
+-----+----------+----------+
| id  | Option_1 | Option_2 |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 123 | 3        | 1        |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 456 | 2        | 3        |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 789 | 1        | 2        |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

item_option_3 table (this would be needed to know which ones are checked):

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
| Sub_Option_1 | Sub_Option_2 | Sub_Option_3 | item_id |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
| 1            | 0            | 1            | 123     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
| 1            | 1            | 0            | 456     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
| 0            | 1            | 1            | 789     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------+
```

item_option_1-2 table (this would be used to print the names):

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| option_id | name         | name_es      |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1         | Sub_Option_1 | Sub_Opción_1 |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 2         | Sub_Option_2 | Sub_Opción_2 |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 3         | Sub_Option_3 | Sub_Opción_3 |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

What kind of structure do I need to spawn these sub options (checkboxes) dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

Your model has option keys as columns and values as rows. Why have both keys and values be rows? If you don't need complex type-based validation, it should suffice to have a single options table with a one to optionally many relationship to itself to account for suboptions. To enumerate all options and values, just retrieve all rows from the table. If `ParentOptionId` is null, then it is a base-level option; otherwise it is a suboption.

UML & ER version below.

[image]

EDIT: After reading through your question and comments again, I've come up with a more complicated but more robust design for you to consider:

[image]

It works like this:

- Every user input is an `Option`. Every option consists of a display text (`OptionText`), tooltip/subtext/etc (`Description`), a default and then user supplied value (`Value`), a value type (`ValueType` boolean,text, date, etc). It also has a `DisplayOrder` so you know where to situate it in relation to other `Options` in its group. `Options` can also have a parent/child relationship with other `Options`. You can do the same for the other entities if you want but I did not model that.
- Every `Option` is contained within an `OptionGroup` with 0 or more sibling `Options`. `OptionGroups` are just a collection of one or  more related `Options`. The `GroupType` field dictates how your form builder needs to treat that group. The most obvious example would be for your radio button groups; each of those would be an `OptionGroup` and each radio button would be a boolean `Option` within the `OptionGroup`. An `OptionGroup` could just as easily handle a multiple selection checkbox group or just some related text inputs that need a common header text (like a street address).
- For further dynamic design `OptionGroups` are contained within `GroupSections`, even if there is  just one default `GroupSection` in a form.
- Finally, a `Form` models your final actual UI form and consists of one or more `GroupSections`.

This should be flexible enough for you to tweak to your liking. What do you think?

Final note: if you are looking into dynamically building your forms in Javascript, check out a few frameworks like [X-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable) or [formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/). They take JSON or configuration objects and build out the entire form with validation/etc from there while giving you some hooks for event handling. Chances are you don't need to completely reinvent the wheel unless you want to keep your implementation as simple and specific as possible.

Comment: I don't fully understand, are id and key columns the same? Sorry I'm more practice than theory. I understand the last thing you said, having options and suboptions in the same table. Could you please provide an example of checkbox and radio button based values? As they are completly different. I still can't picture the structure.

Comment: The id is different than the key. For example, you might have a row with an id of 12, a key of 'CheckboxOption1', a description of 'I can has a cheeseburger', and a value of '1' for checked or '0' for unchecked.

Comment: A radio button group really corresponds to an enum but as long as you synchronize properly is just a group of options. I.e. for a question of 'Choose a color' with options 'Red', 'Blue', and 'Green', you would have 3 options in the database ('Color1IsRed', 'Color1IsGreen', and 'Color1IsBlue') each having a 0/1 or true/false value. You can make it much more complicated by having a table for possible option values (like a lookup for your radio choices) and linking the Options table to a OptionValues table, but keep it as simple as is reasonable for your use case.

Comment: Now I see it more clear. +1 I'm going to think it throught a couple of minutes and I'll accept.

Comment: I'll stick with your first example (the checkbox one). As for the radio buttons, I think you didn't understand well: I don't really need to store nothing (only when adding or deleting suboptions or new options), what I insert is the id of the suboption in the column option of the main table, the radio buttons tables are mainly, as I said, to print the names to generate the form or preview the item, so I think it would be better to separate them as the checkbox are really data inserted but the radio buttons names aren't. What do you think?

Comment: I did not understand your question well enough at first. I am going to bed now but will update my answer for you with a much more complete diagram in the morning (8 or 9) hours from now.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it!

Comment: See my updated answer and let me know if that's more along the lines of what you were hoping for.

Comment: Yes! That's actually what I was looking for. About using javascript to build out the form, I think I'm going to give it a try, mainly because I'd like to give my users a proper validation acordingly with the required format (and also warning them about forbidden characters like <> etc...), this way when they submit, there won't be any error (no rollback, no frustration to re-fill the entire form). Unless these frameworks (I'd prefer simple readable plugins) are too heavy, I'd prefer something light or write it myself. Thanks!